# how to bring drag and drop operations for controls in runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net

For example i've developed a website which contains some controls like button,treeview,etc....Then how can i drag and drop those controls....while running that application....

Comment: Please be more specific on what you mean with dragging and dropping the controls while running the application.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/   --->refer this site....
My requirement was to do the same using C# asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with JQuery. Here's a demo: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

The only issue would probably be saving the positions of controls.